# How to move setting field up a row on general page?

Tags: settings-api

I have added my custom setting field and it appears at the very bottom of the general setting page.

I was wondering if there is any way to place it under tagline field rather than at the bottom? I assume it is the default behavior of wordpress that it display the newly added fields at the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API to add new setting to existed group "general":

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_setting' );
function register_my_setting()
{
    add_settings_field('foo', 'Foo settings', 'foo_function', 'general', 'default', array('label_for' => 'foo'));
    register_setting('general', 'foo', 'foo value');
}
function foo_function()
{
    echo '<input name="foo" id="foo" value="" class="regular-text ltr">';
}
```

You must modify function to validate input and to show saved value.

Comment: I already have added new settings field and it works perfectly fine. What I want is to move it up the row and place it as 2nd option field. Mean my custom field should appear at 2nd position just after "site title" or tagline field. Got it?